# paycheck not running test

Tags: python, testing, random-testing

```
@with_checker([int])
    def check_sort(list_of_ints):
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(list_of_ints, list))
        self.assertTrue(len(list) == len(qsort(list)))
        self.assertTrue(False)
```

I'm trying to run this, but it won't run, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test names must start with "test_"